# How to insert new row with complex key when one column is identity and other is not?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a model for orders. They both are keys and cannot be duplicated. I set `OrderId` as `Identity` in `Map` class.

```
class Order {
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public int OrderNumber {get;set;}
    ...    
}
```

Now I need to generate new OrderNumber to insert the row. I know in SQL I can wrap into transaction and do `MAX(OrderNumber) + 1`, but how can I do it in Entity Framework?

Comment: Why, what purpose does this serve? Why not use `OrderId` instead?

Comment: @Igor I want to group orders by `OrderNumber` and want to avoid possible duplicates when to different orders created.

Comment: 1. You stated above that OrderNumber is unique so you cant group an order by order number according to your above explanation. 2. Using an identity guarantees uniqueness inside that table so again I see no use in having OrderNumber. Are you missing something in the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `OrderNumber` an identity column:

```
class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

By convention, Entity Framework will recognise that OrderId is a primary key; however, it will not automatically be an identity column, so you need so add the `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` to `OrderId` is you want it to be auto-incrementing.

However, if you don't want to change your database, you can wrap your insertion in a transaction:

```
using (var transaction = modelContext.BeginTransaction())
{
    var newOrderNumber = modelContext.Orders.Max(o => o.OrderNumber) + 1;
    var newOrder = new Order { OrderNumber = newOrderNumber };
    ...
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

And then assign this value plus one to your new `Order` object.

Comment: You mean that IsolationLevel.Serializable will be enough?

Comment: Thanks! Could you fix `maxOrderNumber` to `maxOrderNumber + 1` so I can approve it?

Comment: Sure. Approved it.